# Rearrange list of JavaScript array of objects with children list into one object with the parent details inserted inside the child list

Tags: javascript

for example, let's say I have the below array of javascript objects that has a parent list and child list...

```
let accessories = [
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "Elite book",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "HP Envy",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook Pro",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Sat Jul 02 2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Novare central",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "HP workstation",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook air",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to rearrange the above list to form the below single object with the parent object details added to the child list

```
let accessories = [ 
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "name": "Elite book",
    "status": "available",
    "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
  },
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "name": "HP Envy",
    "status": "available",
    "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
  },
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "name": "Macbook Pro",
    "status": "available",
    "date": "Sat Jul 02 2022"
  },
  {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Novare central",
    "name": "HP workstation",
    "status": "available",
    "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
  },
  {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Novare central",
    "name": "Macbook air",
    "status": "available",
    "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
  },
]
```

I don't know if this is even possible but any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is absolutely possible.  Have you attempted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code it should work for you.

```
const accessories = [
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "Elite book",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "HP Envy",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook Pro",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Sat Jul 02 2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Novare central",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "HP workstation",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook air",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const mappedData = [];
(accessories || []).forEach(item => {
  const values = item.computers;
  values.forEach(value => (mappedData.push({
    storeid: item.storeid,
    storename: item.storename,
    name: value.name,
    status: value.status,
    date: value.date,
  })))
});
console.log("accessoriesMappedData", mappedData)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Krishn Kumar, This solution worked well for me. I am just wondering... how efficient could this solution be when it has to handle large data. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```js
const accessories = [
  {
    'storeid': '1',
    'storename': 'Novare station one',
    'computers': [
      {
        'name': 'Elite book',
        'status': 'available',
        'date': 'Tue Jun 14 2022'
      },
      {
        'name': 'HP Envy',
        'status': 'available',
        'date': 'Tue Jun 14 2022'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Macbook Pro',
        'status': 'available',
        'date': 'Sat Jul 02 2022'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'storeid': '2',
    'storename': 'Novare central',
    'computers': [
      {
        'name': 'HP workstation',
        'status': 'available',
        'date': 'Wed Jul 06 2022'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Macbook air',
        'status': 'available',
        'date': 'Wed Jul 06 2022'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const result = accessories.flatMap(item =>
  item.computers.map(element =>
    Object.assign({ 'storeid': item['storeid'], 'storename': item['storename'] }, element)
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, lukas.j for your time and contribution. This solution only removed this  'computers': [ ] from the child object but didn't add the parent items to the child list. Thanks again.

Comment: @GabrielJonah
Thank you for your comment. But I do not understand it: the result is adding the parent items to the children. The result is identical to what you posted as goal.

Comment: You are quite correct. It worked well on the sample data  I posted but when I used it on the actual data coming from the database, It behaved a bit differently, maybe something else might have triggered the different behavior though.

Comment: @GabrielJonah Ok, understood. But it is really important when asking a question to post data which corresponds to the real circumstances.

Comment: Copy that, I'll do just that next time, thanks so much @lukas.j, I really appreciate

Comment: Copy that, I'll do just that next time, thanks so much @lukas.j, I really appreciate

Comment: Copy that, I'll do just that next time, thanks so much @lukas.j, I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

you can combine use `flatMap` and `map` same as :

```js
let accessories = [
  {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Novare station one",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "Elite book",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "HP Envy",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Tue Jun 14 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook Pro",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Sat Jul 02 2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Novare central",
    "computers": [
      {
        "name": "HP workstation",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "Macbook air",
        "status": "available",
        "date": "Wed Jul 06 2022"
      }
    ]
  }
]
const result = accessories.flatMap(({computers, ...rest}) => computers.map(ele => ({...rest, ...ele})))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and time Xupitan, much appreciated